# How to ensure that no one will access my socket?

Tags: python, security, sockets, arduino

I'm developing  a project in my university where I need to receive some data from a set of an Arduino, a sensor and a CuHead v1.0 Wifi-shield on the other side of the campus. I need to communicate thru sockets to transfer the data from sensor to the server but I need to ensure that no one will also send data thru this open socket. On the server side, I need to open the socket using Python 3 or 2.7. On the sensor side, the library of CuHead WiFi Shield lacks important functions to create secure connections. It is possible to ensure this level of security only on the server side? What suggestions do you have for me?

Answer (score 0):

use stunnel at both ends, so all traffic at both ends goes to localhost that stunnel encrypts and sends to the other end